# Question on representing spin states along axis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-states

I am a high school science teacher reading Quantum Mechanics: The theoretical minimum by Leonard Susskind& Art Friedman for my own edification not for any class. One of the exercise in the books asks you to prove that <o|r><r|o> = 1/2 but I keep getting 1/2-i/2 I am pulling the equations for |r> & |o> straight from the book but I can't seem to get the right answer. I have included my work below. Any help on where I am messing up would be appreciated.

From Book:

|u> = +1 z-axis

|d> = -1 z-axis

|r> = +1 x-axis

|o> = -1 y-axis

$\|r> = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} |u> + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} |d>$

$\|o> = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} |u> - \frac{i}{\sqrt2} |d>$

Attempt for <o|r>

$\ 1.1 <o|r>=\ (\frac{1}{\sqrt2} <u| - \frac{i}{\sqrt2} <d|) (\frac{1}{\sqrt2} |u> + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} |d>)$

$\ 1.2 <o|r>= \frac{1}{2}*<u|u> + \frac{1}{2}*<u|d> - \frac{i}{2}*<d|u> - \frac{i}{2}*<d|d> $

$\ 1.3<o|r> = \frac{1}{2}(1) + \frac{1}{2}(0) - \frac{i}{2}(0)- \frac{i}{2}(1)$

$\ 1.4 <o|r> = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} $

Attempt for <r|o>

$\ 2.1 <r|o>=\ (\frac{1}{\sqrt2} <u| + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} <d|) (\frac{1}{\sqrt2} |u> - \frac{i}{\sqrt2} |d>) $

$\ 2.2 <r|o>= \frac{1}{2}*<u|u> - \frac{i}{2}*<u|d> + \frac{1}{2}*<d|u> - \frac{i}{2}*<d|d> $

$\ 2.3 <r|o> = \frac{1}{2}(1) - \frac{i}{2}(0) + \frac{1}{2}(0)- \frac{i}{2}(1)$

$\ 2.4 <o|r> = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} $

Attempt for <o|r><r|o>

$\ 3.1 <o|r><r|o> = (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2})(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2}) $

$\ 3.2 <o|r><r|o> = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{i}{4} - \frac{i}{4} + \frac{1}{4} $

$\ 3.3 <o|r><r|o> = \frac{2}{4} - \frac{2i}{4}  $

$\ 3.4 <o|r><r|o> = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} $

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please don’t post handwritten math.

Comment: Please use the [MathJaX coding tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing out your equations;  the way you've done it is better than an image but is still hard to read.

Comment: That said, your issue appears to be that you forgot to take the complex conjugates of the coefficients when you took the inner products. In particular, $\langle o | = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \langle u | + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \langle d |$, not $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \langle u | - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \langle d |$.

Answer (score 1):

what is o, what is r? If its $|\rightarrow\rangle$ and  $|\leftarrow\rangle$ (i.e., $\hat\sigma_x$ eigenstates), than your first 2 states are manifestly orthogonal.

Maybe you forgot that, if:

$$|\psi\rangle = \alpha|\uparrow\rangle + \beta|\downarrow\rangle $$

then

$$\langle\psi| = \alpha^*\langle\uparrow| + \beta^*\langle\downarrow| $$

?

which matters when $\beta = i/\sqrt 2$.

Idk, it's hard to read a picture. Please redo using the MathJax from this text.

Comment: This is definitely what happened and will solve the problem, even if the question gets deleted. Maybe OP also needs the words "complex conjugation"